# One rigify button missing from the whole body control

Tags: rigging, armature, rigify

After I thought I completely riggged my character, I moved it to animate in my scene. I noticed that the controller for the hand is missing even though the other hand have the controller. [image]

What is the best way to fix this? 
[image]

Comment: I fixed it! Lol, all I had to do was go into pose mode and play around with the rig menu until that missing controller shows up.

Answer (score 0):

It was just missing a layer. So while playing around with the pose mode layers. I had found it.